# Cannot login CentOS 7

Tags: centos

I triple booted my laptop with Windows, Ubuntu and CentOS 7. I accidentally removed the `/boot` partition of CentOS so, now I cannot login in CentOS.

`Kernel missing on partition` error comes when I try login.

Comment: Did you have a /boot for each install?  Are you booting using EFI or legacy BIOS?

Comment: You have unfortunately likely nuked it unless you have backups of the /boot partition, or if it's mounted via lvm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading the minimal CentOS ISO, booting it into rescue mode, and set up the /boot partition again. Once it is mounted, run “yum reinstall kernel”. That will reinstall the most recent kernel, and populate /boot with the appropriate kernel. Normally you’d need to also reinstall grub but it sounds like you are using a different boot loader.